# MongoDB query approach

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have been given below python query by a team-mate to change it to Java implementation.

```
dataCollection = MONGOC['DATABASE_NAME']['COLLECTION']

requests = []

for doc in DATA:
    requests.append(UpdateOne(
        {
            'rId': doc['id'],
            'ts': doc['ts']
        },  
        {
            '$push': {
                'data': {
                    '$each': [{'ms': doc['ts'], 'data': doc['data']}],
                    '$sort': {'ms': 1}
                }
            },
            '$setOnInsert': {
                'ts': doc['ts'].replace(microsecond=0, second=0),
                'regId': doc['id']
            }
        }, upsert=True)
    )
rr = dataCollection.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
```

The request object is in the form of a list. Below is a sample.

```
[   {
     "id" : "582",
     "value" : 5.125,
     "ts" : "2017-05-01T00:55:51.326Z"
    },
    {
     "id" : "582",
     "value" : 5.625,
     "ts" : "2017-05-01T00:55:52.326Z"
    }
]
```

Database document should look like below after executing the java code where data array should be appended if the document is already present.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("XXX"), 
"rId" : ObjectId("582"), 
"ts" : ISODate("2017-05-01T00:55:00.000+0000"), 
"data" : [
    {
        "data" : 5.125, 
        "ms" : NumberInt(2279)
    }, 
    {
        "data" : 5.625, 
        "ms" : NumberInt(2454)
    }
]
```

}

My java code implementation converts the json array to List of Objects. Then I iterate this list and perform the update operation.:

```
DBCollection collection = getDataBaseCollection();
    BulkWriteOperation bulkOperation = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    for(DataList req : regDataList) {
        String timeStamp = req.getTs();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        LocalDateTime ts = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);           
        Date out = Date.from(ts.withNano(0).withSecond(0).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        BasicDBObject o1 = new BasicDBObject(); 
        o1.append("ms", getMilliSeconds(ts.getSecond(), ts.getNano()));
        o1.append("data", Double.valueOf(req.getValue()));
        BasicDBList a = new BasicDBList();
        a.add(o1);

        DBObject aa = new BasicDBObject("regId", new ObjectId(req.getId())).append("ts", out);             
        DBObject dataList = new BasicDBObject("data", new BasicDBObject("$each", a)).append("sort", new BasicDBObject("ts ", 1));           
        DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$push", dataList).append("$setOnInsert", new BasicDBObject("regId", new ObjectId(req.getId())).append("ts", out));

        bulkOperation.find(aa).upsert().updateOne(updateQuery);
        bulkOperation.execute();
    }
```

First document gets added, but the next one does not get appended to data array inside the collection. What is wrong with the java code? Also I want to know if I can use bulk operation to update all the documents at once and not individually.

Comment: Which version of the Java driver are you using here? `DBCollection` and `DBObject` have been deprecated for some time. It is also a lot better to use [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#bulkWrite-java.util.List-) much like the python code does, and therefore consistent across API's. Also note you are calling `.execute()` "within" the loop, negating the purpose of bulk operations. I think if you switch to using the modern API methods you will realize the structure is much the same.

Comment: I am using 2.13.3 version of java driver. Spring boot version is 1.3.1.RELEASE which i guess is out dated. let me try to upgrade the version and see if I can make it work.

Comment: which version do you recommend to use?

Comment: The answer to that is just pretty much always "The latest release supported in all library dependencies". Which usually means start at the most recent and only downgrade where you encounter problems

Comment: I have changed it to 1.5.3-RELEASE which has 1.10.3-RELEASE version for java-mongo driver.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue.  When the document gets added, it also adds sort attribute to the document in the database. How can I prevent this?